# Adding Percentage Number Format in PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel, number-formatting, percentage

When I set format of a cell as %, it automatically multiplies the value with 100 & shows the value. So 94 becomes 9400%.

I want to apply % format on a column but want to keep the values same as before. I just want % sign to be shown along with the value. My Value should be 94% . To achieve this, I used following format code

```
$this->_xls_current_sheet->getStyle($cell_coordinates)->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( 
 array( 
 'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
));
```

Comment: I believe this is due to the way Excel stores percentages. Can you not just divide the cell value by 100 before formatting?

Comment: Looks like [PHPExcel itself](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/f58724ae0b13239fe323d224bf3d13e3a561e143/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.php#L489) is multiplying the cell value by 100.

Comment: This is the code php excel uses for 

} else if (preg_match('/%$/', $format)) { // % number format
582:             if ($format === self::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE) {
583:                 $value = round( (100 * $value), 0) . '%';
584:             } else {

Comment: @amphetamachine - No, PHPExcel doesn't change the value in any way; it's the MS Excel GUI that does a division by 100 to set the value as a percentage

Answer (score 1):

If you store `0.5` in a cell, and format it as a percentage, then it will appear as `50%`.... if you store `50` in a cell, and format it as a percentage, then it will appear as `5000%` that is how it should be.

If you enter `50` as a number in the MS Excel GUI, and then set the format mask manually to a percentage, you will get a displayed value of `5000%`. However, if you enter `50%` in the MS Excel GUI, then MS Excel divides the value by 100 to store `0.5` in the cell, and formats it as a percentage (two actions in one step). If you set `50%` in this way in MS Excel, and then change the format mask from percentage to number, then you will see that MS Excel has done this division for you.

PHPExcel doesn't do this (by default)... it expects you to set the correct value and the format as two separate steps. So PHPExcel expects you to store the correct value in the cell (`0.5`) in the first place, when you want to format it as a percentage.... it will not magically change the value in any way, it doesn't multiply it at all.

Note that if you are using the advanced value binder (rather than the default value binder), and set the cell value to `50%`, then PHPExcel will divide by 100 and set to a percentage automatically, in the same way as the MS Excel GUI.